# is there any shortcut/combo for "cd .." in unix?

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

I found myself typing 'cd ..' quite often.
Just to reduce number of keystroke, Is there any shortcut/key combo I can use to go up one directory?
If not, how do I create one?

Instead of aliasing "cd ..", can I set up something like "ctrl + p"?

Comment: In addition to Ben's answer, consider using `shopt -s autocd` which was introduced in bash 4.0. When you set the option, you can just type `..` instead of `cd ..`

Comment: Is there anyway I can do something like "ctrl + p"?

Comment: just type `cd -`. it will make you go back to previous directory. if you can use `zsh`, it can make you go back any directory in history by setting `auto_pushd`. also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/aliasing-cd-to-pushd-is-it-a-good-idea

Comment: Just how slow a typist are you if typing 5 characters once in a while is a significant impediment to your daily productivity?

Comment: 6 characters, more specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following command can make you execute `cd ..` by pressing `Ctrl+t`

```
bind '"\C-t":"cd ..\n"'
```